# SMPP 3.4 Negative response 0000003e

Tags: java, smpp, jsmpp

I got negative response 0000003e after submit a sms using SMPP version 3.4 (I am using jsmpp 2.1 library). I can't find this error code in any SMPP documentation. Can some one help me to find out this error?

```
String messageId = session.submitShortMessage(
    "CMT",
    TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL,
    NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN,
    "4499",
    TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL,
    NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN,
    "94778845711",
    new ESMClass(),
    (byte)0,
    (byte)1,
    timeFormatter.format(new Date()),
    null,
    new RegisteredDelivery(SMSCDeliveryReceipt.DEFAULT),
    (byte)0,
    new GeneralDataCoding(Alphabet.ALPHA_DEFAULT, MessageClass.CLASS1, false),
    (byte)0,
    "Test message".getBytes()
);
```

Comment: can you maybe show us your code? to do so, edit your post and use code formatting (indent by TAB or 4 spaces).

Answer (score 1):

As per the SMPP spec §5.1.9, `submit_sm_resp` error code `0x0000003E` is a reserved value. Likely your SMSC is using it for some non-standard error, I suggest checking with them.